# nodejs require events to object

Tags: node.js, events

Needs to import all files as events from a catalog to a given object (created in app.js file).

First I create object in app.js:

```
let object = new somting_private_module();
```

and I need add every files from "events_client" as events.
Can someone help me as simple as possible to import these events?

[catalogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeMXm.png)

Comment: Import a file as an event?, I can't understand what you want to do, could you provide more information?

Comment: In the directory I need have all events (one event in one file), because each of these events will be quite complex and searching one file with all events to improve something is quite tedious.

I just want to keep every event in a separate file (about 300-500 lines), because in total they will occupy 20-30 thousand lines, which makes it difficult to prepare anything in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a long time I read about the inherits function, which a colleague sent me and on the basis of her I came to the conclusion that I would do it in a rather uncharacteristic way. I post the results of my work as an answer to your question :)

```js
let object = new class();
require('fs').readdirSync("./events_client").forEach(function (file) {
    object._events[path.basename(file, '.js')]=require("./"+path.join("events_client", path.basename(file, '.js')));
});

console.log(object._events);
```

The solution turned out to be simpler than I thought. Many thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

U can use that f.e.:

```
require('fs').readdirSync("./events_client").forEach(function (file) {
console.log(path.join("./events_client", file));
util.inherits(require("./"+path.join("events_client", path.basename(file, '.js'))), primarymodule);
});
```

:)

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I was looking